# ThreeJS: Add text inside hexagon shape

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have 3  2D Hexagonal shapes interconnected by lines (edges).I want to add 2D text inside the shapes.

How do I add text inside this shapes? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It will be good if you add all the related code.

you can try this js library:

```
<script src="http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.dynamictexture/threex.dynamictexture.js"></script>
```

demo:[here](http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.dynamictexture/examples/basic.html)